# How to accept conditional arguments in a Mongo query?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a method that I call in my Meteor application and the number of arguments it accepts can vary depending on where the call is coming from:

```
myFunc: function (attr){
    if( typeof attr === 'object' ) {
        return Items.update(
                {
                    _id: attr.itemId
                },
                {
                    $set: {
                        field_1: attr.someValue1,
                        field_2: attr.someValue2
                    }
                },
                function (error, result) {});
    }
}
```

In this example, "attr.someValue2" may or may not be in the attr object that is being passed to this function, so what would be the best way to construct the above query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide default values for when the attributes are not supplied in the object argument:

```
myFunc: function (attr){
  if( typeof attr === 'object' ) {
    return Items.update(
      {
        _id: attr.itemId
      },
      {
        $set: {
          field_1: attr.someValue1 === undefined ? attr.someValue1 : 'N/A',
          field_2: attr.someValue2 === undefined ? attr.someValue2 : 'N/A'
        }
      },
      function (error, result) {}
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If someValue1 is undefined, will field_1 retain the value in the database that was there already?